# Flutter: How to remove the extra spaces around a circular elevated button?

Tags: flutter, dart

Here are my two circular elevated buttons. I couldn't figure out what happened here, where the spaces around the buttons aren't desirable. How can I remove them please?

[image]

Below are with overlay guidelines.

[image]

The codes are below:

```
            Row(
              children: [
                // Decrement
                ElevatedButton(
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                    shape: const CircleBorder(), // Makes the button round
                    elevation: 4,
                    minimumSize: const Size(30, 30),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {},
                  child: const Icon(
                    Icons.remove,
                    size: 20,
                  ),
                ),

                // Increment
                ElevatedButton(
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                    shape: const CircleBorder(), // Makes the button round
                    elevation: 4,
                    minimumSize: const Size(30, 30),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {},
                  child: const Icon(
                    Icons.add,
                    size: 20,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is simpler than I expected. Just set the padding to zero (i.e. `padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0)`).

```
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                    shape: const CircleBorder(), // Makes the button round
                    elevation: 4,
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
                    minimumSize: const Size(30, 30),
                  )
```